# Saving multiple translations at once with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.3

I have a tabbed form and in each tab, a set of identical fields that differ in language only. For example, I have a name and description field in each tab, and I would create each input using CakePHP's form helper in the following fashion:

English Tab

```
$this->Form->input("Service.en.name");
$this->Form->input("Service.en.description");
```

French Tab

```
$this->Form->input("Service.fr.name");
$this->Form->input("Service.fr.description");
```

After which (this may be wrong but it worked) I would set the value of a particular field to be an array containing the values keyed by the various locales.

I'm using the TranslateBehavior and all has been well until I upgraded to the most recent of CakePHP (2.4.3 from 2.3). Now whenever I try to save I get an error saying: **Unknown column "Array"**

I can't find anything on saving multiple languages at once. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

**Update 1**

I have also tried moving the locale to the end like so:

```
$this->Form->input("Service.name.en")
```

With same results

**Update 2**

According to xdebug, this is the SQL:

```
UPDATE `cc_dev`.`services` SET `name` = Array, `description` = Array, `duration` = 60, `category_id` = 1, `backend_only` = "0", `id` = 1, `vendor_id` = 116, `updated` = "2013-11-26 18:46:11"  WHERE `cc_dev`.`services`.`id` = "1"
```

And it occurs during save. I simply check to ensure that the request data isn't empty first, and nothing more.

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Service->save($this->request->data);
}
```

**Update 3**

Content of the submitted request data, currently in the format specified in Update 1

```
<pre>Array (
[Service] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [en] => One-to-One Session
                [fr] => Séance individuelle
            )

        [description] => Array
            (
                [en] => Choose a personalized training session of 45 minutes.
                [fr] => Choisissez une séance de formation individuelle de 45 minutes.
            )

        [duration] => 60
        [category_id] => 1
    )
)
</pre>
```

Comment: Could you post the SQL query Cake is trying to execute but fails? Also, can you post the line(s) of code relevant to the error being generated (you said it happens when you try to save)?

Comment: I updated my post to include the requested details.

Comment: One last request: the content of `$this->request->data`.

Comment: Done and done! I seriously appreciate this :)

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused about what you are trying to do here. I assume a `Service` has only a single `name` column in the database, correct? So are you trying to save both names to the single column?

Comment: I am using the TranslateBehavior, and on older versions of CakePHP I was able to submit data in the format specified above, and it would create appropriate translation records in a separate table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Woops, I must have missed when you said you were using the TranslateBehavior. 

Sorry, I have no experience with the TranslateBehavior. I have searched a bit and come across 1 potential problem and 1 potential solution. The potential problem: I believe Cake uses eng/fra where you use en/fr. The potential solution: before your save try doing `$this->Service->locale = array('eng','fra');`

Apologies for the time waste! Hopefully the information I requested will help out more informed individuals.

Comment: One last comment to post a potentially helpful link: http://kristofferdarj.se/2012/05/cakephp-how-to-actually-use-i18n/ - in this they are doing `echo $this->Form->input('Group.name.eng');
        echo $this->Form->input('Group.name.swe');` so maybe something on that page will help you as they are doing quite similar things to what you are trying to.

Comment: No problemo! :) I am actually in the middle of attempting to update to the new language short code. So far I'm getting the same error, but I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working.

The new preferred locale format for CakePHP is based on ISO 639-2, so I updated all current locale records to match. This is especially important when using gettext in Cake as the folder for your *.po files changes (not entirely relevant, but good to know).

After that I changed the structure of my forms to be:

```
$this->Form->input("Service.name.eng");
$this->Form->input("Service.description.eng");
```

Finally, I had to now call saveMany, as opposed to simply calling save being mindful that saveMany expects an array of records.

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Service->saveMany(array($this->request->data));
}
```

So now I can save numerous translations at once again.

Answer (score 0):

The locale is not required to be in ISO 639-2, by default, Cake2 uses it, but in my case, `Configure:write('Config.language') = 'en'` and so my forms were:

```
$this->Form->input("Service.name.en");
$this->Form->input("Service.description.en");
```

It is working great, the only problem i encountered was gathering data from db in the correct format to fit this form automatically.
Before the find function, i used bindTranslation() as stated in CakePhp docs:

```
$this->Service->bindTranslation(array('name'=>'nameTranslation'));
```

Removing or adjusting the contain or adding recursive = 1, it gets the translations, but finally, the nameTranslations must be moved to the Service Index in the array to be in the correct format so the CakeMagic Forms works.

```
'Service' => array(
        'id' => '108',
        'name' => 'Hugs',
        'created' => '1391082480',
        'locale' => 'en'
    ),
    'nameTranslation' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'content' => 'Hugs',
            'locale' => 'en',
            'foreign_key' => '108'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'content' => 'Abrazos',
            'locale' => 'es',
            'foreign_key' => '108'
        )
    )
)
```

As you see, that array format is clear but definitely it is not valid, so i had to add the following foreach to move values and clean it up.

```
$this->request->data['Service']['name'] = array();
foreach($this->request->data['nameTranslation'] as $translation)
     $this->request->data['Service']['name'][$translation['locale']] = $translation['content'];

unset($this->request->data['nameTranslation'],$this->request->data['Service']['locale']);
```

The result was exactly what I was looking for:

```
'Service' => array(
        'id' => '108',
        'name' => array(
            'en' => 'Hugs',
            'es' => 'Abrazos'
        ),
        'created' => '1391082480'
    )
```

It is done and online, but there must be a better way to do it.